# DirPartyTable in form's datasource in AX

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I've added datasource DirPartyTable to form with LinkType OuterJoin. Is it possible to unenabled create record method in this datasource?

```
public void create(boolean _append = false)
{
  //  super(_append);
}
```

Commenting line is not working.

When I clicked button New in the form. The record is trying to be created in DirPartyTable:

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Method `Create` just initializes table buffer in form datasource if you are trying to prevent a record from being stored in the database you need to override method `write`

Comment: I override method create() and write() too.

Comment: Does your logic allow to use one of the Derived tables instead of DiPartyTable (e.g. DirPerson or DirOrganization)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that you are trying to have read-only information from a formdatasource linked to a primary formdatasource with via outer join. Also I assume that when you create new records for the primary data source (such as clicking the new+ button on the form as one example) you don't want it to create dirpartytable records as well.

If these assumptions are correct, try changing the properties of the dirpartytable formdatasource:

- Allow Create: No
- Allow Delete: No
- Allow Edit: No

Comment: Thank you. But in case of DirPartyTable, this properties are not working. Record is still created.

Comment: Yes, DirPartyTable is a formdatasource linked to a primary datasource (outer join). I want to create record only in primary datasource.

Comment: If that is the case, would your use case allow for a display field instead? Find more info on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/using-the-display-method-modifier

Comment: Unfortunately, it could be the only solution.

Comment: If you just need to display a few fields from DirParty table on form you can use replacement field group for your Party field on parent datasource